# Identify service/script running on a port

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump

System specs:

```
Linux client 3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Centos 5
```

I am having some blockages on my DC. I have identified the machine that is making the requests. I also analyzed the outgoing traffic of the requesting machine and it appears to be that one:

```
12:04:13.408750 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22804, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 83)
client.50581 > 192.168.1.30.msft-gc: Flags [P.], cksum 0xbdd6 (incorrect -> 0x7ba4), seq 0:31, ack 1, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 312783772 ecr 911925611], length 31
```

I am not able to identify the service or task that is making this request, I have tried with:

```
netstat -tnp |grep 50581
```

and

```
lsof -i TCP:50581
```

But without result, how could I know who is occupying that port?

Thanks.

Comment: It may be that the session has been closed and there is a new session doing requests. Try to examine `lsof -i` without specifying a port number.

Comment: Very confused. Shouldn't Oracle Linux 8 not ship with at least kernel 4.18, like RHEL 8.0 did? UEK should be even newer? Are you running Oracle Linux with an unsupported kernel, i.e. one that's older than the userland it runs? Doesn't that yield problems?

Comment: err it even says it's a RHEL 7 kernel on a Oracle/RHEL 8 userland

Comment: the client port isn't relevant for your server; your port is `msft-gc`, i.e., 3268. It's also not clear why there *must* be something there. As far as that packet is concerned, it's a *broken* ACK

Comment: Oops my fault, the system is a Centos 5, on the other hand in my DC I have identified the machine that blocks the user, that is the client, that is why analyzing the traffic are the only requests it makes to the DC. My client makes these requests to the DC through port 50581, so I want to identify which process it is or script that is using a wrong credential, isn't it a good starting point?

Comment: Each TCP or UDP connection has both a *source port* and a *destination port*. Usually the client programs don't care about the source port and let the kernel assign it dynamically, so it will typically vary on each individual connection attempt. To catch the connection attempt, you should use the destination port number (as Marcus Müller said), as it is guaranteed to stay the same, as long as the client is trying to contact the same service. My first guess would be that the connection attempts are probably made by either `winbindd` or `sssd`.

Comment: I don't have the winbindd and sssd services running, well then I have to focus on the destination port. Well then what would be the way to save a log or identify which service is doing that specific IP and port? because they disappear instantly and I can't see anything. On the other hand, I know that the ACK is broken, but the DA user's requests come from this server, and you can see that he makes requests to the ADDS services of my DA.